# How to add @Atribute (from Simple XML) anotations on eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, simplexml

I'm trying to use Simple XML to interpret a XML file. Teorically i must add `@Attribute` before `String var;` but i can't do it.

Eclipse tell me this: `"Attribute cannot be resolved to a type"`

How to add these anotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the only possibility is that you don't have the package imported correctly, specifically you need:

import org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute;

There are some other (unusual) complications discussed here [Stack overflow 1910694](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910694/simple-xml-deserialization)