# SimpleXML - How to ignore the class attribute when deserializing

Tags: java, simple-framework

I have problem deserializing this:

```
<tutorial name="tutinteractif1"
    context="MPCaptureCtlr"
    type="interactive"
    class="CaptureTutorialLevelDoors">
```

The problem is that Simple uses `class`attribute ito select the java class to deserialize the xml object with. My question is: **How to tell Simple to use `class` as a standard attribute or at least to ignore it?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910694/simple-xml-deserialization perhaps this can help you

Answer (score 3):

Use a different strategy

```
Strategy strategy = new TreeStrategy("myClass", "myLength");
Persister persister = new Persister(strategy);
```

Now, "myClass" is used instead of "class".